# JUnitCore not loading libs required in test cases

Tags: java, junit, classloader, junit4, dynamic-class-loaders

I am attempting to write a method which dynamically runs an **external** class' test. I am able to run tests which only use JDK libraries, however when I run a test which uses another library such as org.jmock.Mockery, the Result object returned by JUnitCore.run(args) has the following error:

```
[initializationError(package.TestClass): org/jmock/Mockery]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jmock/Mockery

com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

Needless to say, the tests run and pass if I run them from their original project in eclipse.

I believe the issue is related the classpath as the ClassLoader is seemingly only loading the class being tested and not loading dependencies (like jars) defined in the external project's classpath. I don't know how to dynamically load jars to an executing application.

Below is the code loading the class and running the tests.

```
URL url = new File("E:\eclipseProjectName\bin\").toURL();
final URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
final ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
final Class cls = cl.loadClass("package.ClassName");
final JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
final Result result = new JUnitCore().run(Request.method(cls, "methodName"));
```

Thanks in advance,

Mark Cachia

Comment: How are you running the tests? Eclipse, Ant, something else? How are you setting the classpath within the test runner?

Comment: Tests are run programmatically with the code above. I don't know how to dynamically add jars to classpath after execution has started though and I think this is the issue. I have researched a lot and seems like it's impossible to do so, but IDEs do run external tests such as the tests in a program one is coding.

Comment: how do you know, which external jars to load?

Comment: The user will have to specify the path where they are located. My issue is that I don't know how to load them or reference them in the test runner in some way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the libraries which you are using within your application which is running the tests you will want to setup your `URLClassLoader` to load your current classloader and then the reference to the classes you are trying to test

```
 URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Here is an example which loads the classes dynamically from a jar.  If you want to only load your one class by its name you can as you did above.

```
    File pathToJar = new File(jarPath);

    JarFile jarFile;
    jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

    URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{pathToJar.toURI().toURL()};

    URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls, getClass().getClassLoader());
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

        // load all the classes in the jar (or you can set it up to use the exact class/method name as you did above
        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
        if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
            continue;
        }
        // -6 because of .class
        String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
        className = className.replace('/', '.');
        Class c = cl.loadClass(className);


        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.runClasses(c);
        // check for failed/ passed tests here

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> I believe the issue is related the classpath as the ClassLoader is
>   seemingly only loading the class being tested and **not loading
>   dependencies (like jars) defined in the external project's classpath**.

If you want access to a class in java you have to either put it on the classpath or find and load it yourself. It seems like you're adding the Eclipse projects bin path onto the classpath  using your own classloader, but Mockery isn't being added to the classpath. The Eclipse bin path only contains the classes which you have compiled. You'll need to either specifically load the Mockery jar, or better, just put everything onto the classpath of the jvm using `java -cp`.

OK, I'm starting to understand the problem. You're trying to run a set of tests in someone elses project, but it doesn't work if the test refers to other dependencies. The short answer is: this is hard. You're trying to work out which classes you need to add to your classLoader based upon the referenced classes/jars of the external project.

There are a couple of ways to do this. If you are certain that the external project is built with Eclipse, then you can look at the `.project` and `.classpath` to find the dependencies of the external project. This is not simple, because these can contain references to other containers. This is the .classpath from one of my projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
  <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
  <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

This contains references to containers, such as the Maven container. If you think this is achieveable for your projects, this may be one way to achieve this. A much better way would be to enforce the usage of maven or similar, and then you could run the tests just by

```
$ mvn test
```

with the added bonus that if you run & build the projects under jenkins you'll get nice reports as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I wasn't clear. In this application, I will be dynamically loading external tests and running them, thus I don't know what libraries will be used till the user points to his java project. How can I programatically load foreign libraries during runtime please?

Comment: @cachiama: That may be the case for when the actual application runs, but right now we are talking about tests. The tests you write should be deterministic and always produce the same result. Therefore, you should know what dependencies your test code is trying to load.

Comment: Again I believe I did not make myself clear. My application's purpose is to dynamically load external applications' tests and run them and show which tests passed and which did not. The issue is when the external tests are run and use some external library, the JUnitCore in my application internally catches a ClassNotFound exception and the tests obviously fails. I would like to load the libraries used by the external application currently under so the JUnitCore on my application is able to load the classes referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is helpful. This is a proof of concept so far, so I am safe to assume that the project is an eclipse project and  libraries will be stored in any folder in jar format. Do you think it is possible to load such referenced libraries during runtime not added to my app's classpath prior to running?